# React useEffect hook issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to use the React useEffect hook in my code as follows:

```
function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect working')
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HomePage/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But I'm not getting any output on the console, not even errors. I do not understand where the error lies.
**PS:** I'm using the create-react-app typescript template.
I'm willing to provide more information if needed.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Your code looks ok and should work unless there's a problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Just a random guess but do you have any filter applied to your dev console? Maybe that's filtering out your log because the code looks okay.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, [works as expected](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-brook-5of77?file=/src/App.js). Show a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Did you import this component in parent component or root?

Comment: Thanks all for the help, but apparently I found the error in the HomePage component. As I understand, typescript prevented the components from rendering due to the error(a wrongly proxied request) and therefore the hook was not being called.

Answer (score 1):

***if you use this snippet, your code will work***

```
 import {useEffect} from 'react';

 function App() {
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect working')
 },[])
 return (
   <div className="App">
     <header className="App-header">
    
     </header>
  </div>
 );
 }

 export default App;
```